# Should I use Data Warehouse or database or something else?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

On current project we have a webapp with analytics module. The users select some filters and based on those filters table or graph is shown. We want the module to be responsive, so when the users select the filters it can get data in matters of seconds.

User filters are querying a large table ~1,000,000,000 rows and 20 columns (for a few years it should grow 2x/year in rows). 18 out of 20 columns are filtrable. And mostly there will be SELECT + WHERE queries.

We are not sure, should we use Data Warehouses or classical DBs.
Current reasearch suggests we should discuss between Clickhouse, DynamoDB, Snowflake, BigQuery or Redshift. Has anyone had similar use cases and which database solution would you recommend?

Comment: Are these users your internal staff, or is it a public website? How many queries are run each day? Do the queries overlap? Do users really query _all_ the data in the table, or do they tend to just query a particular date range (eg last 30 days)? How much storage does the table occupy (just wondering if it can be kept in memory)?

Comment: It won't be a public website but it will be used by many clients with several users (for now there are 15 users but in a year there will be 200 users etc.) . I would say 50 queries per day by user (inside their working hours).  They will usually query small subset of data (~1% of whole data) which differes from user to user. Also,  I would say that each user uses the same filters 80% of time. Currently there is around 100GB of data and it should grow 10GB per month.

Comment: It's really a trade-off between performance and cost. Amazon Redshift can easily handle billions of rows and performance is based upon how the data is stored and sorted on disk (Distribution Key, Sort Key). However, it is your call whether it is worth running a Redshift cluster full-time for your userbase. Amazon Athena is a lower-cost option (priced on usage rather than server time), but you'd need to test whether it gives you the desired speed (hint: Use partitioned Parquet files!). I'd say start simple with a normal PostgreSQL database, then try Redshift if it doesn't perform well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the database for analytics purposes, it is recommended to use a OLAP ( Redshift)..
an OLAP database is designed to process large datasets quickly to answer questions about data.
You can compare the pricing here

https://medium.com/2359media/redshift-vs-bigquery-vs-snowflake-a-comparison-of-the-most-popular-data-warehouse-for-data-driven-cb1c10ac8555

Comment: Are SELECT queries considered as a "analytical purposes" as it is fairly simple query? As I understood, for fast retreival of data OLTP suits us better? I would emphasize that we need really quick retrieval of data. Doesn't Redshift have some start overhead which could make fetching slower? Thank you for youer anwser!

Comment: Depends on the complexity of the query..DB like DynamoDB has a limitation when it comes to complex queries and executing queries containing multiple search criteria and sorting based on different columns could be tricky. On the other hand, Redshift has great performance in the case of complex queries scanning millions of rows.

Comment: Do you consider "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Country='X' and City='Y'" on a billion rows a complex query? What makes it complex, the number of rows or a query itself?

Comment: If you are not using complex queries like joining multiple columns, you can follow @John Rotenstien's comment